# How to shutdown computer if no LAN connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, lan, shutdown

I would like to switch off my computer if my router goes offline or gets disconnected from the LAN. What I need is a way to start monitoring status concurrent with starting Windows, and keep checking whether the router is connected to the LAN. If it gets disconnected for whatever reason, I would like to get a 90 second warning that the PC is about to shut down, allowing me to cancel the shutdown.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy paste this into `Notepad` and save as `Shutdown.cmd`:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Ping switch/router
    PING 192.168.1.1 | FINDSTR TTL
    ECHO Errorlevel is %ERRORLEVEL%

REM Ping responds
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO :ConnectedToLAN

REM Ping does not respond
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO :NotConnectedToLAN

GOTO :eof

:ConnectedToLAN
    ECHO Connected to LAN
    GOTO :eof

:NotConnectedToLAN
    ECHO Not connected to LAN
    MKDIR %tmp%\TKH\Connected_to_Internet
    REM VBScript to make popup dialog
    (
        ECHO.Option Explicit
        ECHO.Dim oShell, retCode
        ECHO.Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
        ECHO.retCode = oShell.Popup^("Shutdown computer now? If no answer is given within 90 sec computer will shutdown.", 90, "Shutdown?", 4 + 32^)
        ECHO.Select Case retCode
        ECHO.   case 6, -1
        ECHO.       WScript.quit^(0^) 'Yes or time-out was chosen
        ECHO.   case 7
        ECHO.       WScript.quit^(1^) 'No was chosen
        ECHO.End Select
    )>"%tmp%\TKH\Connected_to_Internet\Shutdown.vbs"
    CSCRIPT //nologo "%tmp%\TKH\Connected_to_Internet\Shutdown.vbs"
    ECHO Errorlevel is %ERRORLEVEL%

    REM Timeout or clicked Yes (Shutdown)
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 SHUTDOWN /P /F

    REM Clicked No (Do nothing)
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 REM

REM Clean up
    RD /Q /S "%tmp%\TKH\
```

Open `Task Scheduler` (search for it in the start menu).

Create a new task, give it a name.

Under `Trigger` put `At log on`, `Repeat task every:` choose repeat interval you'd like (how often to check for LAN-connection, `for a duration of: Indefinitely`.
Under `Action` Click `New...`, `Start a program`, `Browse...` and locate the `Shutdown.cmd` file you recently created.
Press OK twice to create the task.
Find the task you just created and right click and choose `Run`.
A dialog box should show up like this:

[image: Shutdown dialog]

Edit `Shutdown.cmd` to suit your needs (router address etc.).

VBS-script comes from here: [Link](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/138818-vbscript-msgbox-with-auto-select-countdown-and-batch-script-input/).

Comment: how can make that batch file run silently, I mean that task should run in background, task is running fine, but that batch file i created should start minimized or in background only.

Comment: @RohitPanchal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411247/running-a-cmd-or-bat-in-silent-mode

Comment: program works perfectly but it doesnt shut down pc even if i click for yes option nor if I dont respond to message.

Comment: I found that same to be true when I tested now. Will update the script in a minute or two :)

Comment: Now it works. Seems like the command `shutdown /s /p /f` did not work because the `/s` is unneeded. Also I removed the `goto` commad there as it is not supposed to be there.

Comment: still its not working, let me know if i am using this script correctly, i changed the router address to 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.1.1 and then i saved it as shutdown.cmd and after that if i disabled the lan connection and then I runned the program, it shows the message if you want to shutdown yes or no and then if i click yes then again same message pops and it keeps doing the same thing over and over again and still it doesnt shut the windows

Comment: I fixed the script, thank you for your help, problem was that you suggested to save name by shutdown.cmd so when program asks me to shutdown if i say yes then i calls program shutdown.cmd instead of shutting down windows.

Thank you.